# Как отлавливать блокировку экрана

Tags: android, java

Как понять что экран заблокировался ну или потух?

Comment: @asdasdasd, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Для этого существуют специальные Intent-ы. `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF & Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON.` 
Для того чтобы ваше приложение получало данные интеняы следует задать IntentFilter для Вашего активити. Для этого можно наследоваться от класса BroadcastReceiver.
Вот хороший пример из интернета.  [Источник](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/)

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // THANKS JASON
    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE
            wasScreenOn = false;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // AND DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE
            wasScreenOn = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Затем задаем интент фильтр для Вашего активити.

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        // INITIALIZE RECEIVER
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        // YOUR CODE
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // WHEN THE SCREEN IS ABOUT TO TURN OFF
        if (ScreenReceiver.wasScreenOn) {
            // THIS IS THE CASE WHEN ONPAUSE() IS CALLED BY THE SYSTEM DUE TO A SCREEN STATE CHANGE
            System.out.println("SCREEN TURNED OFF");
        } else {
            // THIS IS WHEN ONPAUSE() IS CALLED WHEN THE SCREEN STATE HAS NOT CHANGED
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // ONLY WHEN SCREEN TURNS ON
        if (!ScreenReceiver.wasScreenOn) {
            // THIS IS WHEN ONRESUME() IS CALLED DUE TO A SCREEN STATE CHANGE
            System.out.println("SCREEN TURNED ON");
        } else {
            // THIS IS WHEN ONRESUME() IS CALLED WHEN THE SCREEN STATE HAS NOT CHANGED
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    boolean isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();

    if (!isScreenOn) {
        // Делайте что Вам надо если потух экран.
    }
}
```

И для включения

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    boolean isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();

    if (isScreenOn) {
        // Делайте что Вам надо если включен экран.
    }
}
```

Решайте, что Вам больше подходит.

Comment: Как то все слишком много всего вам не кажеться?. Да к тому же разве нелезья как то через WindowsManager реализовать это...Да и  ктому же я использую Сервис

Comment: Много не есть плохо, почитайте про Broadcast receiver. Вам тем или иным образом надо будет получать интенты от системы. Вам нужно зарегистрировать свой ресивер в интент фильтре Вашего активити. Еще можно сделать с помощью PowerManager.Посмотрите обновление ответа

Comment: Я решил проблему другим способом....Незнаю почему, но вы могли бы написать что при блокировке вызывается Pause или Resume....Вот и вся проблема. все тему можно крыть

Comment: Вы почитайте внимательно, какие методы я переопределил у Активити ?